# wordpress - listing custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Right now I'm using the following code to list my 'Skills' taxonomy:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'Skills', '', ', ' ) ?>
```

I have three questions:

1. Is that the correct (most elegant)
   way to write that?
2. Also, is there a way to list the
   parent category first separated by a
   pipe with the children categories
   after that? *Like this: Illustration
   | Charcoal, Watercolor, Pen*
3. Is there a way to have the
   categories NOT linked text?

Update:

```
<?php
    $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Skills', '', ', ', '' ) ;
    echo strip_tags($terms_as_text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. You must use a custom function based on get_the_term(), see below
3. Yes, use [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I took a look at that link and tried substituting `get_the_term_list` with `get_the_terms` but it didn't work. Can you please explain where I'd insert or how I'd use `get_the_terms()`?

Comment: get_the_terms() return only an array of items. You must do a foreach on it to obtain the results. do a print_r(get_the_terms()) to see which fields a term has!

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. Unfortunately, I have little experience with php and am not able to understand what I need to do. If you can help me through it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Update: I managed to get the list to print out without links (updated code in original post). Now I just need help with my second question only. Am I on the right track with this btw?